# Script to switch between networks in ubuntu using nmcli

Tags: networking, command-line, bash, scripts, nmcli

I'm trying to switch between already populated networks using a bash file using **nmcli** but I'm get non sense data back.

But get nonsense

```
1) 0
#? 0
```

Code below.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Pre-populated UUID data for network connections
networks=(
    ["tr_5"]="127f3e9e-34dd-444e-aee4-7c2b35c7c307"
    ["VC_HotSpot_6"]="c498aa6a-24d4-4b51-92c7-9b8d84181fc1"
    ["Network_3"]="34567890-3456-3456-3456-345678901234"
)

# List available network connections
echo "Available network connections:"
nmcli connection show

# Prompt the user to choose a network
echo "Select the network to connect to:"
select network_name in "${!networks[@]}"; do
    if [[ -n $network_name ]]; then
        break
    fi
done

# Get the UUID of the selected network
network_uuid=${networks[$network_name]}

# Check if the network UUID exists
if [[ -z $network_uuid ]]; then
    echo "Network '$network_name' UUID not found. Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

# Disconnect from the current network (if connected)
current_connection=$(nmcli connection show --active | awk 'NR>1{print $1}')
if [[ -n $current_connection ]]; then
    echo "Disconnecting from the current network..."
    nmcli connection down $current_connection
fi

# Connect to the chosen network
echo "Connecting to network '$network_name'..."
nmcli connection up uuid $network_uuid

# Display the connection status
echo "Connection status:"
nmcli connection show --active | grep -E "($network_name|$current_connection)"

echo "Network switch completed successfully!"
```

I run the script ./network_switch.sh

But get nonsense

```
1) 0
#? 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this, it's helpful to use the `declare` builtin to examine the result of the assignment:

```
$ networks=(
    ["tr_5"]="127f3e9e-34dd-444e-aee4-7c2b35c7c307"
    ["VC_HotSpot_6"]="c498aa6a-24d4-4b51-92c7-9b8d84181fc1"
    ["Network_3"]="34567890-3456-3456-3456-345678901234"
)

$ declare -p networks
declare -a networks=([0]="34567890-3456-3456-3456-345678901234")
```

You will see that you have created an *indexed* array (`-a`) with a single 0th element. That's because the `name=(...)` syntax creates indexed arrays by default, and it simply evaluates the string-valued "keys" as numerical 0 and successively overwrites the value.

To create an *associative* array you need to declare it explicitly, either

```
declare -A  networks=(
    ["tr_5"]="127f3e9e-34dd-444e-aee4-7c2b35c7c307"
    ["VC_HotSpot_6"]="c498aa6a-24d4-4b51-92c7-9b8d84181fc1"
    ["Network_3"]="34567890-3456-3456-3456-345678901234"
)
```

or

```
typeset -A  networks=(
    ["tr_5"]="127f3e9e-34dd-444e-aee4-7c2b35c7c307"
    ["VC_HotSpot_6"]="c498aa6a-24d4-4b51-92c7-9b8d84181fc1"
    ["Network_3"]="34567890-3456-3456-3456-345678901234"
)
```

which you can then check with `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p networks
declare -A networks=([tr_5]="127f3e9e-34dd-444e-aee4-7c2b35c7c307" [Network_3]="34567890-3456-3456-3456-345678901234" [VC_HotSpot_6]="c498aa6a-24d4-4b51-92c7-9b8d84181fc1" )
```